# Transparent window in ElectronJS not working Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: electron, transparent, ubuntu-22.04, wayland

I have this for a transparent window in ElectronJS:

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-transparent-visuals');
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('disable-gpu');
```

I have a problem with Ubuntu 22.04 and Wayland disabled, sometimes the windows is black and sometimes windows is transparent.

It works with Ubuntu 20.04.

Does anybody know how could I fix this?

Thx!!!